# Canot build Android NDK project after latest NDK update and gcc deprecation

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have updated Android NDK to latest version available and now my project doesn't compile anymore.
At the first attempt to compile the project I received a message about `gcc` deprecation and invite to replace It with `clang`.

So I have tried to edit

```
externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    arguments '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc', '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static'
                }
            }
```

In

```
externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    arguments '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang', '-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static'
                }
            }
```

But unfortunately now I get the error:

```
Error while executing process C:\Android\android-sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HD:\My Project\myApp\jni -BD:\My Project\myApp\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\My Project\myApp\gradleBuild\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Android\android-sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Android\android-sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Android\android-sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang -DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static}
```

The project compilation before the NDK update worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't try to build NDK when the path to your sources contains spaces.
2. The latest NDK deprecated gnustl, too. Try c++_shared instead.
3. You don't need to specify ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN in **arguments**.
4. Make sure you use a version of gradle Android plugin that is compatible with the latest NDK, see https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

> This runtime is tightly coupled to GCC, which is no longer supported in the NDK. As such, it has not received updates for several releases. The version in the NDK supports most of C++11 (see Issue 82), and some portions of this library are incompatible with Clang.

[gnustl](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support#gnustl/%22gnustl%22)

> This library is deprecated and will be removed in NDK r18. Beginning with NDK r16, you should use libc++ instead.

You should use `"-DANDROID_STL=c++_static"` instead of `-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static`